# What Happens When two concurrent threads try to remove elements from a CopyOnWriteArrayList? java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In JAVA What Happens When two concurrent threads try to delete some elements from the same CopyOnWriteArrayList? Will there be an undefined behaviur?
For Example if there are 1-10 Integers in a list and,
1 Thread removes first 5 Integers
2 Thread removes first 3 Integers
The accurate result would be to have a list with the first 5 Integers removed.
Will this work properly?

Comment: I'm not sure Java can provoke 'undefined behaviour'.

Comment: There is no undefined behaviour. Java defines its [memory model as well as its execution order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) in great detail. If both threads access the same list. By looking into `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, one finds that e.g. `add(E e)` utilizes a `ReentrantLock` to guard the critical section. Therefore, subsequential calls to `add(E e)` block until the lock in question is free to acquire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of CopyOnWriteArrayList will depend on the method you are using.

If you do `remove(int index)` with 5 in one thread and 3 in another you will remove 8 elements, although which thread gets which elements is not defined.

If you do `remove(Integer element)` for the find 5 values in one thread and the first 3 value sin another thread, provided there is no duplicates, the first 5 elements will be removed.  The first three elements could be removed by either thread, leaving the thread which didn't remove the element being returned `false`

Comment: What happens if I used the iterator concurrently to do the remove operation ?
So there will be 2 threads accessing an iterator object of the same list. this according to the documentation creates a copy of the list  Hence the name CopyOnWriteAList.
What happens if I use a counter and try to do the concurrent element removal using iterator.remove()?

Comment: @jdc91 Iterator.remove() on CopyOnWriteArrayList always throws UnsupportedOperationException "The iterator does <em>NOT</em> support the method."

Answer (score 1):

If  you remove by index then total 8 (5+3) elements will be removed.
Since, after one element deleted by one thread new CopyOnWriteArrayList will have lesser element than the one on which delete was performed earlier.

```
package com.copyonwrite;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> cop = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            cop.add(Integer.toString(i));
        new Thread(new DeleteRunnable(cop, 5)).start();
        new Thread(new DeleteRunnable(cop, 3)).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("size " + cop.size());
    }

    public static class DeleteRunnable implements Runnable {

        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> cop;
        int cnt;

        public DeleteRunnable(CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> cop, int cnt) {
            this.cop = cop;
            this.cnt = cnt;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                cop.remove(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Output: size 2

Comment: What happens if I used the iterator concurrently to do the remove operation ? So there will be 2 threads accessing an iterator object of the same list. this according to the documentation creates a copy of the list Hence the name CopyOnWriteAList. What happens if I use a counter and try to do the concurrent element removal using iterator.remove()?

Answer (score 0):

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` is actually used in multi threading environment, with *best results wherein writes are less and reads are more*.

All the **threads carry a copy of List**, and the original list in left intact. Before any *add/remove operations*, monitor looks at the original list, a copy of the whole list is made each time you write to the list like adding an element or remove an element and `synchronization` happens.

This can be pretty expensive when your list is too large.
This means that a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is mostly useful when we have few modifications but many reads because reads are very cheap and don’t require synchronization.

As per documentation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java),

> A thread-safe variant of java.util.ArrayList in which all mutative
>   operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh
>   copy of the underlying array.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList uses a CAS rather than a lock.